# why doesn't tar preserve file permissions?

Tags: linux, tar

I have noticed that a tarball created on one linux does not preserve the file permissions when extracted on another linux.

How can I make tar preserve the file permissions?

Comment: Have you tried `tar -pxvzf xxx.tar.gz` from [link](http://www.aota.net/forums/showthread.php?t=21329)

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [su] or [unix.se]

Comment: Sorry about that, I did not realize this question should go to a different site.  Not only that, but I am apparently blind (or I have been staring at this monitor for too many hours today), because I checked the man page before I posted this question and did not see it.  Thanks for your responses guys.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `p` option, both when creating the tarball and when extracting it.

Answer (score 28):

Can you try:

```
tar -pcvzf xxx.tar.gz
```

p == preserve permissions
c == create archive
v == verbose (print names while making tar)
z == gzip
f == tar file name

[Source](http://www.aota.net/forums/showthread.php?t=21329)

Comment: I keep having `tar: p: Cannot open: No such file or directory` erro what may be the reason

Answer (score 5):

Having a short look at the manpage clarifies your issue:

```
 -p, --preserve-permissions, --same-permissions
       extract information about file permissions (default for superuser)
```

But mind, that untaring your archive on some filesystems like FAT won't preserve permissions as they don't support it.

Also the numeric owner / access time preserve might be intersting to you:

```
 --numeric-owner
       always use numbers for user/group names

 --atime-preserve
       preserve access times on dumped files, either by restoring the
       times
```