# File permissions are not being preserved while after unarchive tar.gz

Tags: java, apache-commons

I'm trying to unarchive tar.gz file using Apache Compress library under Linux with Java.

How can I preserve files permissions using Apache Compress library when unarchiving tar.gz?

```
public void run(ByteTransferCallback callback) throws IOException
{
    this.entries = new HashSet<>();


    try (TarArchiveInputStream tarArchiveInputStream = new TarArchiveInputStream(
            new GzipCompressorInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(this.tarGZipFile)))))
    {
        TarArchiveEntry entry = null;

        while ((entry = tarArchiveInputStream.getNextTarEntry()) != null)
        {
            if (entry.getName().startsWith(this.tarGZipPath))
            {
                boolean cancelled = !unarchiveEntry(tarArchiveInputStream, entry, callback);
                if (cancelled) break;
            }
        }

    }

}


protected boolean unarchiveEntry(TarArchiveInputStream tar, TarArchiveEntry 
     entry, ByteTransferCallback callback) throws IOException
{
    File entryDestination = new File(this.destination, 
    entry.getName().replaceFirst(this.tarGZipPath, ""));

    entryDestination.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    this.entries.add(entryDestination);

    boolean result = false;

    if (entry.isDirectory())
    {
        entryDestination.mkdirs();
        result = true;
    }
    else
    {
        result = unarchiveFileEntry(tar, entry, entryDestination, callback);
    }

    return result;
}



protected boolean unarchiveFileEntry(TarArchiveInputStream tar, 
TarArchiveEntry entry, File destination, ByteTransferCallback callback) 
throws IOException
{
        try(OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination))
        {
            return copy(tar, out, callback);
        }
}


protected boolean copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out, 
ByteTransferCallback callback) throws IOException
{
    int numBytes = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];

    boolean cancelled = false;

    while (EOF != (numBytes = in.read(buffer)) && !cancelled)
    {
        out.write(buffer, 0, numBytes);
        cancelled = !callback.onBytesTransferred(numBytes);
    }

    return !cancelled;
}
```

From each entry, I can get permission in Unix format using TarArchiveEntry.getMode(), but how I can set it to each unarchived file?

Comment: how are you coding it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why doesn't tar preserve file permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338215/why-doesnt-tar-preserve-file-permissions)

Comment: My question is different from  [why doesn't tar preserve file permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338215/why-doesnt-tar-preserve-file-permissions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Linux/Unix there's no way for a normal user to transfer the ownership of a file system object to another user. Only `root` (UID 0) can.
In this case your program needs to be run as `root` and you need to use the system call `chown()` and related (see `man 2 chown`).

For the file permissions and time and date you need to use the system call `utime()` and related ones (see `man 2 utime`).

You can do this from Java with the methods available in `java.io.File` like `setExecutable`, `setReadable`, and `setWritable`.
Please refer to [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) for the details.

Comment: This means I have to read and parse each file unix permission via getMode() and set it to all files with setExecutable(boolean) and etc.. ? This is error prone!

Comment: This is what the `tar` tool does under Unix/Linux. This is what's needed!